# Want to know all possible Parent and Child Rows against specific Id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**How to know all possible Parent and Child Rows against specific Id?**

e.g. have following table:

**MyTable:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   Id    |    PId    |   Description               |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    1    |   NULL    |    A is Parent              |
|    2    |     1     |    B is Child of A          |
|    3    |     2     |    C is Child of B          |
|    4    |   NULL    |    D is Parent              |
|    5    |   NULL    |    E is Parent              |
|    6    |     5     |    F is Child of E          |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

want to know all possible parent and child when pass spesific id

e.g.

**CASE-01:**

When ***@MyLookupId=2*** OR ***@MyLookupId=1*** OR ***@MyLookupId=3*** One of from them Then Result Should Be,

```
-------
| Id  |
-------
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
-------
```

**CASE-02:**

When ***@MyLookupId=4*** Then Result Should Be,

```
-------
| Id  |
-------
|  4  |
-------
```

**CASE-03:**

When ***@MyLookupId=6*** Then Result Should Be,

```
-------
| Id  |
-------
|  5  |
|  6  |
-------
```

> Here is SQL for table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTable; 
SELECT * INTO #MyTable FROM (
    SELECT (1)Id, (NULL)PId, ('A IS Parent')Description UNION ALL
    SELECT (2)Id, (1)PId, ('B IS Child of A')Description UNION ALL
    SELECT (3)Id, (2)PId, ('C IS Child of B')Description UNION ALL
    SELECT (4)Id, (NULL)PId, ('D IS Parent')Description UNION ALL
    SELECT (5)Id, (NULL)PId, ('E IS Parent')Description UNION ALL
    SELECT (6)Id, (5)PId, ('F IS Child of E')Description ) AS tmp

SELECT * FROM #MyTable
```

Comment: Where is there is 1 child of '6'  say `7`. Now for lookupid=5, do you want this child too?

Comment: 5 is parent and 6 is child of 5 so yes both should be in result.

Comment: Use CTE with levels to identify position... there are a number of CTE cases here or the basic CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `recursive cte`

```
-- temp returns full tree of each rootId (parentid = null)
;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT sd.Id, sd.PId, sd.Id AS RootId 
    FROM #MyTable sd
    WHERE sd.PId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sd.Id, sd.PId, t.RootId  
    FROM temp t
    INNER JOIN #MyTable sd ON t.Id = sd.PId
)

SELECT t2.Id
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN temp t2 ON t2.RootId = t.RootId
WHERE t.Id = @Id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/RAITMT72805

Comment: @Haseeb Be sure to test the performance of this across your dataset, as it requires a full tree calculation - including for `ID` values that you aren't searching for - before it can drop out the relevant results.  This amount of redundant recursion across a wide number of values may have significant, unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @iamdave thanks for advice I need apply it on large number of rows so let me check and will post my comments here... also thanks for your great answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by TriV works, but requires a calculation of the entire hierarchy of your source table each time the query is run, which may not perform well at larger scale.

A more narrow approach is to find the Parent and Child records that only relate to the `ID` you are searching for:

```
declare @t table(ID int, PID int);
insert into @t values(1,null),(2,1),(3,2),(4,null),(5,null),(6,5);

declare @ID int = 2;

with c as
(
    select ID
            ,PID
    from @t
    where ID = @ID

    union all

    select t.ID
            ,t.PID
    from @t t
        join c
            on(t.PID = c.ID)
)
,p as
(
    select ID
            ,PID
    from @t
    where ID = @ID

    union all

    select t.ID
            ,t.PID
    from @t t
        join p
            on(t.ID = p.PID)
)
select ID
from p

union all

select ID
from c
where c.ID <> @ID
order by ID;
```

Output:

`````
 ID
````
 1
 2
 3
`````